# Bird Photography Camera System

Tags: bird-photography

The camera should have fast focus, high res, good clarity, good night capture without noise, silent ... Is there anything bird photography does not require in a camera? I mean which Nikon or Canon camera should be bought if money is not a concern (it is, please suggest decent compromises also).

Also, what camera cana give me a larger field of view and a marking to show the actual photographed area (useful when using telephoto lenses to locate the subject in the field of view)?

Also if you can suggest the lens to go with it... I think a 600 prime will best, no?

-SM.

Comment: Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets, are off topic here. Please rephrase your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve or what you do not understand that prevents you from determining the answer yourself.

Comment: If you have to ask this kind of question, start with a less expensive camera (superzoom). Bird photography takes a lot of skill. A 600mm lens is complicated to use (weigh, and aiming...). And you can't shoot birds you can't see, so long lens is not that useful. A 20$ "ghillie suit" will get you closer to birds than a $2000 lens.

Comment: Why Nikon or Canon only? A strange restriction to impose on yourself. "a marking to show the actual photographed area" - I've no idea what this means. "good clarity" - what does it mean? "Clarity" is not a well-defined photographic term. "Good night capture" - how dark are the conditions you are going to be capturing these nocturnal birds in? "high res" - are there any cameras anymore that _aren't_ high res?

Comment: Many of the bird photographers I see are using Sony mirrorless and the zoom that goes to 600mm.  I use a Nikon P1000 which goes out to an effective focal length of 3000mm.  It has a snap back on the lens to help you find the bird but when you take the photo what you see is what you get.  It isn't easy.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic, being a question that is primarily about seeking specific product recommendations. We currently have over 800 questions/posts that are returned if you [search for "bird"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=bird) on this site. Some of the searched questions may direct you: [What lenses should I use for bird photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/117242); [Birding on a budget?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40621); [How to calculate which system will work better for me?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96877/); amongst man others...

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for something that does not exist.

The only cameras I am aware of that can show a wider field of view and simultaneously record/mark a smaller field of view is a full frame DSLR recording in a (DX) crop mode... I know at least some Nikon DSLR's do this, but the mirrorless cameras do not.

The only cameras that record silently are mirrorless, or are operating as mirrorless (live view). And in that mode they cannot show a wider FOV.

High resolution inherently means less clarity (contrast) and more noise (worse low light performance) at the pixel level. Not really at the image level, but it's more of a tradeoff.

And the "best lens" will depend on everything else... i.e. longer lenses are generally slower; which means they ultimately can project/record less resolution, and less light.